# Resize and rotate image - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rotation, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize and rotate a image.

At the moment it's only resizing the image, but not rotate it.

Here is the code, hope someone have a solution or something :-)

```
$config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
$config['source_image']    = $data['full_path'];
$config['new_image']       = $data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['file_name'];
$config['create_thumb']    = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
$config['width']           = 235;
$config['height']          = 235;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

$this->image_lib->resize();

$this->image_lib->clear();

$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE; //No thumbnail
$config['source_image'] = $data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['file_name']; //full path for the source image
$config['rotation_angle'] = '180';// 

$this->load->library('image_lib',$config);

//Rotate the image
$this->image_lib->rotate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

`$this->image_lib->clear();`

add:

`$config = array()` to re-initialise your config array.

Answer (score 3):

After clearing the configuration, don't reload the library, reinitialize it:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
$config=array();
$config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = $data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['file_name'];
$config['rotation_angle'] = '180';
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); // reinitialize it instead of reloading
$this->image_lib->rotate();
```

This is the only solution that finally worked for me. Just re-initialising $config did not work out in CodeIgniter 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you recreate the $config before sending it again.

Otherwise you might end up sending values you don't want to send.

At the moment rotate() gets a $config like this:

```
$config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
$config['new_image']       = $data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['file_name'];
$config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
$config['width']           = 235;
$config['height']          = 235;
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE; //No thumbnail
$config['source_image'] = $data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['file_name']; //full path for the source image
$config['rotation_angle'] = '180'; //
```

Comment: Do you have any example, if I want to rotate the original image + the new thumbnail image?

Comment: I think it's because you double load the 'image_lib'. Remade my answer.

Comment: Try creating your $config through $config = array(); in both cases instead. It might not work since you're "trying" to modify width and height in `rotate()`.

Comment: The first config is where I resize, the second is the rotating. They don't have the same config settings. Do you have an example?

Comment: They do since you don't recreate the $config array. You simply build on it and you parse 'new_image', 'width' and 'height' to the rotate(). Try print_r($config) before rotate() and you'll see.

Comment: I think I figured out why there was an error, but now I get this error:
Call to undefined function imagerotate() (and GD is installed)

Comment: Add a phpinfo(); to the top of one of your files, see if GD is working as you'd expect.